# Start animation when user see this

Tags: css

I have the source below, which is positioned in the footer page, what I need is start an animation when user scroll down and see it :

```
<div class="box_one padding_top_bottom_40 centered">
<div class="circle transition_05 animated bounce"><img padding_top_35 animated bounce" src="img/icons/1.png"></img></div>
<p class="title_4 black_c padding_top_20">Made with love</p>
<p class="title_3 black_c padding_top_20">I am some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the animation? You need to paste your CSS code

Comment: You want to a) identify the scrollTop() position of the top of your content, and b) trigger then animation only once the user has reached that y coordinate.

Answer (score 0):

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom) using that you can activate your animation when user reaches the bottom.

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
     if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    // you're at the bottom of the page
    document.getElementById(div id here).className = animation class;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) :

> Waypoints is a jQuery plugin that makes it easy to execute a function whenever you scroll to an element.