# Infinite text repeat with infinite scroll on web page

Tags: html, infinite-loop, infinite-scroll, infinite

How do I make a web page repeat the content (a block of text) every time a user hits the end of the web page – like with infinite scroll, but with the same content?

Comment: Marquee? and jQuery for detecting scroll from top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A thread that already answers your question:

[Javascript how to detect if browser window is scrolled to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom)

And to make it infinite you simply append a tag with its content every time the "window-bottom" state is reached.

This could be expressed as such:

```
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
        // you're at the bottom of the page
        var div = document.createElement('div')
        div.innerHTML = "your content"
        document.body.appendChild(div)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make the div element of a certain class? I added `div class="repeat_content"` but that doesn't work?

Comment: With the chance of me missunderstanding; you can set the new div to be of a specific class by merely adding:

`div.className="repeat_content"`

Answer (score -1):

```
<marquee>Scrolling text</marquee>
```

Comment: The `<marquee>` tag is deprecated and may not work in all browsers.

Comment: http://remysharp.com/demo/marquee.html

Comment: no this does not work

Comment: you'll have to download jquery