# how to detect user is in bottom using javascript in desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what i need

- when user scroll down the page i need to add class using js.

problem

- its appending class at last of scrolling page.
- i need to add class 300px above.

  ```
  jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8PkQN/1/
  ```
- i have tried with : (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) == $(document).height()

  code

  ```
      var bottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
     if($(window).scrollTop() + 1 >= bottom - 2200==true)
    {
        $(".abslouel_left12").addClass("fixed_left_btm");
    }
  ```
- working code

  ```
            window.onscroll = function(ev) {
       if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
     $(".abslouel_left12").addClass("fixed_left_btm");
   }
  };



  $(window).scroll(function() {
       $(this).scrollTop() > 75 &&            
    ($(".abslouel_left12").addClass("fixed_left"), 
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()), 

       $(this).scrollTop() < 75 && ($(".abslouel_left12").removeClass("fixed_left"),

   )

        if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {

  $(".abslouel_left12").removeClass("fixed_left");
    }
  ```
- case 1 when user is at top. no class to be added.
- case 2 when user scroll down add class (.fixed_length).
- case 3 when user scroll to bottom add class(.fixed_length_btm)
  but the issue is case 3 code is working end of scrolling browser i need it should above footer of page .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to detect if browser window is scrolled to bottom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom)

Comment: Needz moar bullet points

Comment: If any answer below uses `==` instead of `>=`, feel free not to trust them in production.

Comment: @Brian Oddly enough, i scoffed a little at your comment until I played around a little and found when I was trying to just find above footer had been reached == did NOT work like it did for just the bottom of the page. If you scroll very quickly it doesn't always hit. I updated my answer. You sir are correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has always worked for me:

```
if (window.pageYOffset == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
    // bottom of page
}
```

If you want to know they reach above footer you can add the footer height into the calculation.

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $('footer').height()) {
    // top of footer
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8PkQN/449/

Alert happens when you reach the top of footer. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: [Always use ===](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
      //addClass('fixed_length_btm');
    } else {
      //removeClass('fixed_length_btm');
    };
  });
```

`$(document).scrollTop()` will give you the scrolled height. You will be in the bottom of the page when the document height is equal to the scrolled height plus window height.

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.