# How to tell bottom of page has been reached?

Tags: selenium, browser, watir

I'm trying to use Watir (via Ruby) to jump down the page using the space key, on a page that has infinite scroll. How can I tell if the bottom of the page has been reached?

I found an SO answer with [some JavaScript that says when](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9439807/335847). Could I use that to pop up a dialog (via `execute_script`) if the bottom has been reached and check for the dialog?

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just try this:

```
@browser.scroll.to :bottom
```

And if that doesn't work:

```
@browser.driver.executeScript("if((window.innerHeight+window.scrollY)>=document.body.offsetHeight){return true;}")
```

could surely be used to scroll until it returns `true`.

Comment: The first one scrolls fine but doesn't indicate when I've reached the bottom. The second one returns the info but the javascript doesn't always work! (o_O) Being able to get feedback via the script though is immensely helpful, thank you, I'll be able to get further with this now.

Comment: This js appears to work `br.execute_script("if (document.body.scrollHeight == document.body.scrollTop + window.innerHeight) { return true; } else { return false; }")`. I think you did enough for the tick! :)