# Programmatically detect when or right before closing Body Tag is hit on a web page using JS?

Tags: javascript

I want to know if there is a way to detect with JavaScript when I have reached the bottom of a webpage, right before the closing "body" tag?

***I can't add any code manually/directly to the HTML pages, this needs to be handled via a JS included script therefore this is why I need to detect programatically***

I want to fire a method right before the closing body tag.

Comment: [Javascript: How to detect if browser window is scrolled to bottom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom)

Comment: How do you "reach" the closing body tag? Do you scroll down, or do you mean in the markup, or what ?

Comment: @adeneo - when the page is first loading, NOT when a user scrolls.

Comment: Why not use [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) or [*load*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load) events?

Comment: @RobG - I think DOMContentLoaded is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just add a script element right before the closing body tag

```
<script>doWork();</script></body>
```

Or to add this programmatically

```js
    var scr = document.createElement('script');
    scr.innerHTML = 'console.log("body closing")';
    document.body.appendChild(scr);
```

```html
<div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: Script elements don't contain markup, they contain text so more semantic to set the *text* property. But anyway, I think the OP means when the user scrolls to the bottom of the visible page (or not…).

Comment: @Travis J sorry, I should have been more clear, I can't add anything manually to the pages, as you've suggested, hence why I need to detect via JS.

Comment: @RobG - No I don't mean when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page, I mean when the page initially loads.