# Infinite scroller with html content

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen a lot of videos explaining how to do an infinite scroller, but all of them require a database to load and then show some content. Isn't it possible to do an infinite scroller using the divisions I already have designed on HTML?

To make it more clear here is a code with some boxes in it: https://jsfiddle.net/hugot1944/0fbuvsrz/10/

Isn't it possible to make an infinite scroller with these divisions tagged as boxes? Can't I initially show, let's say, from the box with the ID box1 to box6, and then whenever a user scrolls show another 6 divisions?

Here is the code of the divisions I'm talking about:

```css
/*Box Wrapper Design*/
.boxWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 2em;
    grid-row-gap: 5em;
    margin-top: 120px;
}

.boxWrapper .box{
    background-color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    width: 300px;
    height: 355px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.boxWrapper .box img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 84.5%;
}

.boxWrapper .box a{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.boxWrapper .box p{
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
}
```

```html
<div class="boxWrapper">
  <div class="box" id="box1">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
      <p>Character 1</p>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
      <p>Character 2</p>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
      <p>Character 3</p>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box4">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
      <p>Character 4</p>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box5">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
      <p>Character 5</p>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box6">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
      <p>Character 6</p>
      </a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="box" id="box7">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
      <p>Character 7</p>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box8">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
      <p>Character 8</p>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box9">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
      <p>Character 9</p>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box10">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
      <p>Character 10</p>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box11">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
      <p>Character 11</p>
      </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box12">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
      <p>Character 12</p>
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40599047/basic-infinite-scrolling-lazy-loading-blog-posts-with-pure-javascript

Answer (score 0):

First you need to understand the concept of scroll, **"scroll (on the webpage) only happens when the content of your site is more than the viewport height.And one can only scroll till he/she reaches the end of the content on the particular page"** .

Now, in your case the data is **static**, you have divs, which ultimately takes their respective heights and finally once a user scrolls to the last div, that's it. **Since no further content/data, No scroll.**

> So, a straight forward answer is with the above static setup, it is
> not possible to have an infinite scroll. For Infinite scroll, we must have data loaded from the Backend API as the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

Comment: Right, this goes only for infinite scroll, or is it the same with a load more button that has the same objective in mind? (the only difference would be the need to click in the button instead of the scroll event)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample for you hope it helps.

```js
// Here is what you need
// I tried to make it as simple as possible for you

var currentNumOfBoxes = 6;
  var boxWrapper = document.getElementsByClassName('boxWrapper')[0];
  
  function createBox(num) {
    var newBoxNumber = num + 1;
    
    var box = document.createElement("div");
    box.setAttribute("class", "box");
    box.setAttribute("id", "box" + newBoxNumber);
    
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", "/characters/character1.html");
    
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute("src", "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png");
    
    var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.innerHTML = "Character " + newBoxNumber;
    
    link.append(img);
    link.append(paragraph);
    box.append(link);
    boxWrapper.append(box);
    
    currentNumOfBoxes++;
  }
  
  window.onscroll = function(ev) {
    if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
      createBox(currentNumOfBoxes);
    }
  };
```

```css
/* Your CSS I didn't touch here */
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #737373;
  }
  
  /*Box Wrapper Design*/
  .boxWrapper{
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 2em;
    grid-row-gap: 5em;
    margin-top: 120px;
  }
  
  .boxWrapper .box{
    background-color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
    width: 300px;
    height: 355px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .boxWrapper .box img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 84.5%;
  }
  
  .boxWrapper .box a{
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  
  .boxWrapper .box p{
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
  }
```

```html
<!-- Here your 6 initial box. I didn't touch here -->
  <div class="boxWrapper">
    <div class="box" id="box1">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
        <p>Character 1</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box2">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
        <p>Character 2</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box3">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
        <p>Character 3</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box4">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
        <p>Character 4</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box5">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
        <p>Character 5</p>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="box6">
      <a href="/characters/character1.html">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png"/>
        <p>Character 6</p>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function atEnd() {
  var c = [document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight, document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight].sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a
  }) // select longest candidate for scrollable length
  return (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY + 2 >= c[0]) // compare with scroll position + some give
}
// This is the no. of divs we start with
let start = 4;
// This is the number we load every time the user reaches end
let newboxes = 4;
// Hide all boxes by default
let boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
boxes.forEach((box) => {
  box.classList.add('hidden')
})
// Show some boxes as start
for (let i = 0; i < start; i++) {
  boxes[i].classList.remove('hidden')
}
// Set event listener for scroll
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  // If all boxes have appeared then return
  if (start == boxes.length) return
  // if the user is not at end then return
  if (!atEnd()) return
  // If everything is right load some more boxes
  for (i = start; i < start + newboxes; i++) {
    boxes[i].classList.remove('hidden')
  }
  start += newboxes
})
```

```css
/*Box Wrapper Design*/

.boxWrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 2em;
  grid-row-gap: 5em;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.boxWrapper .box {
  background-color: rgb(241, 240, 240);
  width: 300px;
  height: 355px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.boxWrapper .box img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 84.5%;
}

.boxWrapper .box a {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.boxWrapper .box p {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: rgb(22, 22, 22);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="boxWrapper">
  <div class="box" id="box1">
    <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png" />
      <p>Character 1</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box2">
    <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png" />
      <p>Character 2</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box3">
    <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png" />
      <p>Character 3</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box4">
    <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png" />
      <p>Character 4</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box5">
    <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png" />
      <p>Character 5</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box6">
    <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png" />
      <p>Character 6</p>
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="box" id="box7">
    <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png" />
      <p>Character 7</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box8">
    <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png" />
      <p>Character 8</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box9">
    <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png" />
      <p>Character 9</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box10">
    <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png" />
      <p>Character 10</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box11">
    <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png" />
      <p>Character 11</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="box12">
    <a href="/characters/character1.html">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Blue_Square.svg/781px-Blue_Square.svg.png" />
      <p>Character 12</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```