# Fixed Navigation Flickering

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, navigation, fixed

**Scenario:** I have built a fixed navigation function that adds a class to the header once the scroll is greater or equal to 200px, the height of the nav.

**Issue:** Although the function executes properly, on certain screen sizes the navigation tends to flicker and deny the function to properly run. I'm not sure if it is because the bottom of the window does not exceed 200px?

**Desired:** I would like the navigation to properly execute the sticky nav function regardless of screen size.

**Question:** What is the issue in my jquery conditional? Does it have to do with the `.scrollTop()` function?

**Note:** Here is a screen capture of the navigation bug: [Error Capture](http://beta.synchronygroup.com/error/)

**JS Code:**

```
// Side navigation Sticky function
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(top >= 200) {
        $('header').addClass('navbar-fixed-top')
    } else {
        $('header').removeClass('navbar-fixed-top')
    }
});
```

Here is the link to the prototype: **[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WeebleWobb/LzcmLgzn/)**

Answer (score 1):

That's because of your `else` section. Scenario is:
1. adding class
2. Not enough tall page's now lower.
3. `if` isn't true anymore
4. It's executing your `else` section.
5. Page is again tall enough...

You should implement something that can block `else`. Maybe check something like "onbottom"? Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom)