# check if the user has reached to bottom of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to trigger an event when the users scrolls down and reaches to the bottom of the page.

I searched the internet and found some posts in stackoverflow but unexpectedly the answers did not work for me.

Ex: [Check if a user has scrolled to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130)

using the answers given for the above SO post, the event I am trying to trigger is executed when reaching the top of the page and not the bottom.

Please let me know if I am going wrong:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   loadmore();
}
});

function loadmore(){

var lastProd = $('.product_div').last(); 
var lastProdID = $('.product_div').last().prop('id'); 
//console.info(lastProdID); return false;
//var val = document.getElementById("row_no").value;
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'includes/load_products.php',
    data: { getresult:lastProdID },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        //var content = document.getElementById("all_rows");
        //content.innerHTML = content.innerHTML+response;
        lastProd.after(response);

        // We increase the value by 10 because we limit the results by 10
        // document.getElementById("row_no").value = Number(val)+10;
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? It will be hard to help you without something reproducible.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle with the code you currently have?

Comment: Ok I will create a jsfiddle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to detect if browser window is scrolled to bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom)

Answer (score 5):

Use `window.innerHeight + window.scrollY` to determine bottom position and check if `document.body.offsetHeight` is lower (equal won't work).

Credit goes to [mVChr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246616/mvchr), [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9439807/6331369).

```js
window.onscroll = function(ev) {
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    alert("bottom of the page reached");
  }
};
```

```css
.jump {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jump"></div>
```

Comment: *Credit goes to [mVChr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/246616/mvchr), [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9439807/6331369)* - Then mark/flag it as a duplicate so they actually get the credit.

Comment: I had to change it a bit for it to work on android chrome, with the hiding address bar, the result of `(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight)` was off by a few decimals, so i changed it to : `(window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= (document.body.offsetHeight - 1))` for it to work as expected

Answer (score 2):

check the height and offset are equal

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  var d = document.documentElement;
  var offset = d.scrollTop + window.innerHeight;
  var height = d.offsetHeight;

  console.log('offset = ' + offset);
  console.log('height = ' + height);

  if (offset === height) {
    console.log('At the bottom');
    loadmore(); // call function here
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The only proper way to do this, at time of writing Feb/11/2022, is here: [Check if a user has scrolled to the bottom in subpixel precision era](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55419779)

That detects bottom of scroll for any element. To do this with the "window" in a default web page, you should set `element` to `document.documentElement` or `document.scrollingElement` to get the result you want.

Or, apply the same `Math.abs` trick as in that answer with `window.scrollY`, but not that that does not work with scrollable in any other elements, only the `documentElement` (that's what element is being scrolled when saying "window scroll", and it is the root `<html>` element).