# How to detect if browser window is scrolled to the right edge?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I saw that I can detect if the browser window is scrolled to bottom.

[How to detect if browser window is scrolled to bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom)

But I wonder if it is possible to detect if the browser window is scrolled to the right edge of a page since I am making a horizontally long page.

Comment: Have you tried using the solution in the linked question with all the vertical properties replaced with their horizontal equivalents? Essentially using `(window.innerWidth + window.scrollX) >= document.body.offsetWidth` as the predicate

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
if ( $(document).scrollTop() == ( $(document).height() - $(window).height() ) {
  // Do something here ...
}
```

check here..

http://jsfiddle.net/cNmhR/24/