# Detecting continuious scrolling after end of page scroll

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, lazy-loading

I'm trying to detect continuing scrolling at the bottom of the page.

The page shows more information when reached at the end of the page but I want to show that when people scroll more at the end.

I can detect the end of the scroll, but I want to detect if people are continuing to scroll.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
function scrolling() {
    let scrollView = document.getElementById('field-scroll');
    if ($(scrollView).scrollTop() + $(scrollView).innerHeight() >= $(scrollView)[0].scrollHeight) {
        alert('end of the bottom. but I want to show it when doing more scroll not immediately');
    }
}

<div id='field-scroll' onscroll='scrolling()'>
   ...
</div>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: How to detect if browser window is scrolled to bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica No, mine is working as same as your comment. I want to detect 'More Scrolls' at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a variable to indicate the first-time end of scroll, and then check that variable to know if the user continued scrolling.

```
function scrolling()
{
    let scrollView = document.getElementById('field-scroll');

    if($(scrollView).scrollTop() + $(scrollView).innerHeight()>=$(scrollView)[0].scrollHeight)
    {
        // first end of scroll
        window.endOfScroll = true;
    } else {
        // unset the variable
        window.endOfScroll = null;
    }
}
```

Also, you need to listen for scrolling events. Add these outside of the `scrolling` function.

```
const scrollView = document.getElementById('field-scroll');

// mouse wheel
scrollView.addEventListener("wheel", event => {
    const direction = Math.sign(event.deltaY);
    // if user is scrolling down at end of scroll
    if (direction === 1 && window.endOfScroll) {
        showMore();
    }
});

// down arrow
scrollView.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    // if user is pressing down arrow at end of scroll
    // 40 is the keycode for down arrow
    if (event.keyCode === 40 && window.endOfScroll) {
        showMore();
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is, when reached to bottom, onscroll doesn't work for bottom. ( becuase no scroll height left for bottom. ) It means, need to scroll up, and down. And I think, it is not good experience to user.. I just wander is there any 'trick' for it.
By the way, thanks for the answer :)

Comment: @EugeneFitzher I have updated the answer. See if it can help you :)

Comment: Thanks <3 I changed direction value to 1 ( heading bottom ), and it wokrs fine. ! !

Comment: @EugeneFitzher Glad it helped you. I thought scrolling down was -1, my bad. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

se the .scroll() event on window, like this:

```
    $(window).scroll(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       alert("bottom!");
   }
});
```

Behzad fartash