# Svelte: How to fetchMore if a user has scrolled to end of page

Tags: fetch, apollo, svelte, scroll-position

I have a Component which fetches posts from a graphql server. It shall fetch more posts if the user is at the bottom of the page. How can I check if he has reached it? I looked on clientHeight, innerHeight and outerHeight but only clientHeight made any sense to work with from those. Probalby I have to substract somethin from it but I don't know how what exactly and what I am missing?

```
<script>
    import {getClient, query} from 'svelte-apollo';
    import ContentWrapper from '../layout/ContentWrapper.svelte';
    import {GET_POSTS} from "../services/posts/postsApi";

    let pageInfo;
    let first = 2;
    let after;

    const client = getClient();
    let posts = query(client, {query: GET_POSTS, variables: {first}});

    const fetchMore = () => {
        posts.fetchMore({
            variables: {first, after},
            updateQuery: (previousResult, {fetchMoreResult}) => {
                const newEdges = fetchMoreResult.getPosts.edges;
                const pageInfo = fetchMoreResult.getPosts.pageInfo;

                return newEdges.length
                        ? {
                            getPosts: {
                                __typename: previousResult.getPosts.__typename,
                                edges: [...previousResult.getPosts.edges, ...newEdges],
                                pageInfo
                            }
                        }
                        : previousResult;
            }
        })
    };

    const setState = queryData => {
        pageInfo = queryData.getPosts.pageInfo;
        after = pageInfo.endCursor;
        return '';
    };

    let y;
    let clientHeight;

    const checkScrollPosition = () => {
        if(clientHeight <= y)
            fetchMore();
    }
</script>

<svelte:window on:scroll={checkScrollPosition} bind:scrollY={y} />

<ContentWrapper>
    <div slot="header">
        <h4>Page of Pagination</h4>
    </div>
    <div slot="body" bind:clientHeight={clientHeight}>
        {#await $posts}
            <h3>Loading...</h3>
        {:then result}
            {setState(result.data)}
            {#each result.data.getPosts.edges as post}
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <p class="card-text">{post.node.body}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {/each}
            <div id="paginator">
                {#if pageInfo}
                    {#if pageInfo.hasNextPage}
                        <div class="btn" on:click={fetchMore}>Next</div>
                    {/if}
                {/if}
            </div>
        {:catch error}
            {console.log(error)}
        {/await}
    </div>
</ContentWrapper>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript: How to detect if browser window is scrolled to bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom)

Answer (score 2):

The [Intersection Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) is what you are looking for in the question. The technology is supported by all modern browsers. With it, you can find whether some element is visible on a screen and, after that, fetch more items.

You can take a look at the [Svelte IntersectionObserver component](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/master/site/src/components/IntersectionObserver.svelte) implementation right here: it uses both the technology the old-fashioned way with window.innerHeight

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's a simple workaround that I used, in case the height of your scrollable div is fixed for all screen sizes.

- So, First of all, enclose it in a `div` and in CSS, set the `overflow: scroll` and the `height: 600px` (any fixed height)
- Then on `localhost`, run this function in console of your browser's dev tools, `getX()` and note down the value that is returned *(We'll call it 'x'):*

```
const getX = () => {
  let myDiv = document.querySelector('my-div-id')
  myDiv.scrollTop = myDiv.scrollHeight;
  return myDiv.scrollHeight - myDiv.scrollTop;
}
```

- Then in your Svelte component:

```
<sript>
    let x = 585 // the value returned by getX() function
    let contentLength = 10; // number of items that load on the page initially
    
    const loadOnScroll = (elem) => {
       if (elem.scrollTop >= (elem.scrollHeight - x) ) {
         contentLength += 10; // load more as user scrolls to bottom
       }
    }
</script>

  <div id="my-div-id"
  on:scroll="{ () => loadOnScroll(document.querySelector('my-div-id')) }" >

    {#each items as item, i}
        {#if i < contentLength}
          <ul>
            <li>        
                <!-- Do something with item -->
            </li>
        </ul>
        {/if}
    {/each}
  </div>
```

This will load 10 more fetched items from your API each time the user scrolls all the way to the bottom of the div. I know it looks kinda scattered, but hey, it works ;)