# How to automatically add HTML tags when the page scrolls to the bottom through javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am a javascript beginner!
There is currently a project like this. I hope to automatically add 5 groups of HTML when scrolling to the bottom of the page through javaScript.

For example, add 5 groups of HTML
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.

But I found the information on the Internet and I still don’t know what to do. Write, so come to ask everyone~ thank you all.

```js
let demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
let contain = document.querySelector('#contain');
let str = `<div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>`;

function addDemo(){
   if(contain.height == (window.height + window.scrollTo)){
     console.log('123')
     // demo.appendChild(str);
   }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll',addDemo);
```

```css
.demo{
  padding:20px;
  border:2px solid #222;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain">
   <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
   <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
   <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
   <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
   <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
   <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
   <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
   <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
   <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
   <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
   <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
   <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I’m not sure what are you looking for like this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would first be concerned with your `str` being added to all the `demo` elements. You have queried them all. Do you want to add to each `demo`? Or just the last `demo`? Please clarify.

Comment: @Twisty
Sorry ~ I didn't clarify the question!
I hope that when I scroll to the bottom of the page,
I will add 5 more after the original last demo, but I haven’t learned javascript for a long time and I’m not sure how to write to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
let demo = document.querySelector('.demo');
let contain = document.querySelector('#contain');
let str = `<div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>`;

function addDemo(event) {
  if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
    console.log('Reached Bottom of Page, add 5 more.');
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      contain.innerHTML = contain.innerHTML + str;
    }
  }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', addDemo);
```

```css
.demo {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #222;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="contain">
  <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
  <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
  <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
  <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
  <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
  <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
  <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
  <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
  <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
  <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
  <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
  <div class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</div>
</div>
```

Based on the following: [Javascript: How to detect if browser window is scrolled to bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/javascript-how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom)

Comment: First of all~Thank you for the solution!
It seems to be what I want. I am studying your code. Can I ask you again if I have any questions?

Comment: @AWEI You can ask. I would advise that you give it your best effort first, search around, and if you get stuck, post a new question.