# Sticky right side on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

I want to fix the right side and make scrollable content on the left side.
I tried added position fixed for left div but it doesn't work for me,
Please help me out
https://8jpezuv3zaya3g0a-40229470359.shopifypreview.com/products/7-am-citrus-toilet-spray?variant=36679664009367

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you make it fixed it would still cover other content of the page. I would have helped you if the content to the right wouldn't create a problem for your users. Instead, have a **add to cart** button appear at the bottom when the user scrolls down.

Since you are using JQUERY, you can check out this tutorial on how to detect when the user scrolls down the page https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-when-user-scrolls-to-the-bottom-of-a-div/ and then show your footer pannel. I'll attach a preview of what I am suggesting.

[image: this should appear fixed]

This should appear fixed on the bottom of your window only on scroll.

I also have a pure javascript method to track when a scroll happens, you may also want to try that out. [How to detect if browser window is scrolled to bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9439725/how-to-detect-if-browser-window-is-scrolled-to-bottom/46718465#46718465)