# Getting Infinite-Scroll by paulirish to work on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, infinite-scroll

I've been implementing Infinite-Scroll by Paul Irish on my site. It works on desktop browsers, but on mobile (iPhone specifically) it doesn't straight away. The work around is zooming in slightly, that makes the scroll event fire which triggers infinite scroll.

Also see the issue report here:
https://github.com/paulirish/infinite-scroll/issues/3

My question is: is there a solution for this?

I've noticed Tumblr makes infinite-scroll work without a workaround.

If you were to check http://youworkit.tumblr.com/ on iPhone, then switch from the mobile to the standard desktop view, infinite-scroll does work without zooming in.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

[JQuery Detect Scroll at Bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220267/jquery-detect-scroll-at-bottom)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
```