# Infinite scrolling is not working on iPhone 4

Tags: mobile

Following infinite scrolling script working nice on desktop and Android web browser, but not working on iPhone 4. What should I modify for make it work for iPhone and Android?

"#more" is div ID for mysql query output.

Here is part of script

```
var page = 1;
$(window).scroll(function () {
 $('#more').hide();
 $('#no-more').hide();

 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height() - 200) {
   $('#more').css("top","400");
   $('#more').show();
 }

 if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {

 $('#more').hide();
 $('#no-more').hide();

 page++;
```

Comment: This is a duplicate **SO Question** [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10952179/1195891).

Comment: Thanks. I found some useful information on that link.

Answer (score 0):

Old Code : 
Old Code below work only pc browser.

```
if ((($(window).scrollTop()+document.body.clientHeight)==$(window).height()) && isload=='true'){
```

New Code :
I just change == to >=. It work on Android (Chrome) and iOS too

```
if ((($(window).scrollTop()+document.body.clientHeight)>=$(window).height()) && isload=='true')
```

Answer (score -2):

try to replace this :

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height())
```

By this :

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height())
```